# How do I send form data to HttpPost Action with Postman in ASP .Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, postman, http-post

Out of simple curiosity I would like to Post data from my MVC app to my local database with Postman. Unfortunately, I encountered a certain obstacle and cannot figure out how to solve it.

The general idea is that I have a controller X with an Edit method accepting YViewModel as the only parameter.

```
XController : Controller
{
    //Post 
    IActionResult Edit(YViewModel vm)
    {
        //Code
    }
    //Get
    IActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        //Code
    }

}

YViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //Other fields below
}
```

In the **Edit** method with an **HTTP GET** Verb I am returning the respective view with the YViewModel containing all the required fields. All the fields (except Id) are assigned to form inputs.

The Id is only bound to the VM model. Binding works perfectly on the page, but I cannot compose the right Postman Request.

I know that I can try **localhost..../X/Edit** with **form-data** and then assign all the form fields. But where do I fit **Id** in that request?

Answer (score 1):

Under the `Body` tab select `x-www-form-urlencoded`. For `Key` use `Id`. For `Value` use whatever you want to test with.

I assume you would want to post other `YViewModel` fields for testing.

Ensure you are creating a POST request.

If `Id` as the `Key` doesn't work you can load the page in your browser and look for the `name` attribute of the `Id` hidden field. Then use that in Postman.